# Are there any known or theoretical mechanisms to prevent a singularity?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

General Relativity tells us that the force required for a particle to escape when an object's size subseeds its Schwarzchild radius is infinite.

It follows that a singularity forms inside every black hole, which seems to defy common sense. But what mechanism exists to prevent such a thing inside a black hole?

Comment: The first paragraph describes an event horizon, not a singularity. Basically the answer to the question is no, although it's possible that quantum gravity would prevent it.

Comment: @BenCrowell isn't a singularity a logical conclusion from the event horizon? If the force required to escape is infinite, how can anything inside of it have a finite size in equilibrium?

Comment: Equilibrium implies stationarity, but inside the black hole horizon singularity is not a place but rather future moment in time. Or in other words, time flows toward singularity.